# Keeping the arc length constant between points in a spiral

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, polar-coordinates

I'm making a visualization of points in a [logarithmic spiral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LogarithmicSpiral.html) and want to keep the arc length between points (image particles) constant. [I read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19114508/drawing-text-in-a-spiral-in-processing) that in an [Archemedian spiral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ArchimedeanSpiral.html) arc length is `s = r * theta`. I've been fiddling with that and can't quite understand how to implement it (replace theta with `s/r` where `s` is an arbitrary constant and increment only `r`?), and then how to apply it to the case of a logarithmic spiral.

Here are my two test case spirals below, with images. I'd appreciate a nudge in the right direction on how to get these image particles evenly spaced throughout each spiral form. Kind thanks!

An **Archemedian spiral**, with image:

```
// ARCHEMEDIAN SPIRAL
var r = 1;
var theta = 1;
for (var p = 0; p < particleCount; p++) {
    var pX = r * Math.cos(theta);
    var pY = r * Math.sin(theta);
    theta += 1;
    r += 10;
    // make an image particle at pX, pY
```

[image: archemedian spiral]

A **logarithmic spiral**, with image:

```
var r = 1;
var theta = 1;
var a = 100; // a constant
var b = 0.2; // another constant
for (var p = 0; p < particleCount; p++) {
    var pX = a * Math.cos(theta) * Math.exp(b * theta);
    var pY = a * Math.sin(theta) * Math.exp(b * theta);
    theta += 0.1;
    // make an image particle at pX, pY
```

[image: logarithmic spiral]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Logarithmic spiral

### Approximate solution

The logarithmic spiral is self-similar. As a consequence of that, the tangents make the same angle with the position vector in each point of the spiral. You can use that to draw a reasonable approximation of the spiral simply by taking unit steps in the direction of the current tangent.

Perhaps it's easiest to look at this in terms of complex numbers:

$$
z(\theta)=ae^{(i+b)\theta}=a\left(e^{i+b}\right)^\theta\\
\frac{\mathrm dz}{\mathrm d\theta} = ae^{(i+b)\theta}(i+b)
$$

So the direction vector is the position vector rotated by $(i+b)$, which means the angle between them is

$$\alpha=\arctan\frac{1}{b}=\operatorname{arccot}b $$

So the above approach would be something like this (written in sage code):

```
def logspiral1(s):
    hypot = sqrt(1 + b^2)
    sinA = 1/hypot
    cosA = b/hypot
    x = 1
    y = 0
    for c in range(100):
        yield (x, y)
        f = s/sqrt(x^2 + y^2)
        dx = f*(cosA*x - sinA*y)
        dy = f*(sinA*x + cosA*y)
        x += dx
        y += dy
```

Looks like a log spiral if taken all by it self, but since errors accumulate it will diverge considerably from the parametric equation.

### Exact solution

To avoid that, you should probably compute the new $\theta$ in terms of the direction you want to take. Doing so accurately would mean integrating curve length.

$$\int_{\theta_1}^{\theta_2}\left\lvert
ae^{(i+b)\theta}(i+b)\right\rvert\,\mathrm d\theta$$

According to [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20%7Ca*exp%28%28i%2Bb%29*t%29*%28i%2Bb%29%7C%20dt) this can be computed using

$$\int\left\lvert ae^{(i+b)\theta}(i+b)\right\rvert\;\mathrm d\theta=
\frac{\lvert a(b+i)\rvert}{b}e^{b\theta}$$

so you want

$$
s=\frac{\lvert a(b+i)\rvert}{b}\left(e^{b\theta_2}-e^{b\theta_1}\right) \\
e^{b\theta_2}=\frac{sb}{\lvert a(b+i)\rvert}+e^{b\theta_1} \\
\theta_2=\frac1b\log\left(\frac{sb}{\lvert a(b+i)\rvert}+e^{b\theta_1}\right)
$$

```
def logspiral2(s):
    theta = 0
    h = s*b/(a*sqrt(1 + b^2))
    for c in range(100):
        yield (a*cos(theta)*exp(b*theta), a*sin(theta)*exp(b*theta))
        theta = log(h + exp(b*theta))/b
```

The first, approximate approach is drawn in red in the following figure, the second exact one in green. The continuous line behind the green points is a simple parametric plot of the exact solution.

[image: Figure of logarithmic spirals]

## Archimedean spiral

### Attempted exact solution

So let's do the same for the Archimedean spiral, again using [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20r*sqrt%281%2Bt%5E2%29%20dt).

$$z(\theta)=r\theta e^{i\theta} \\
\frac{\mathrm dz}{\mathrm d\theta} = r(1+i\theta)e^{i\theta} \\
\int\left\lvert r(1+i\theta)e^{i\theta}\right\rvert\;\mathrm d\theta = \int r\sqrt{1+\theta^2}\;\mathrm d\theta
=\frac r2\left(\theta\sqrt{1+\theta^2}+\operatorname{arsinh}\theta\right)$$

That last term is a real beast: it includes $\theta$ both inside and outside the transcendental function $\operatorname{arsinh}$ (the inverse sinus hyperbolicus), which means we probably won't be able to solve this expression for $\theta$ except perhaps numerically.

### Approximate solution

You could again do this thing we did above, take unit steps in tangent direction. Since the tangent direction angle depends on $\theta$, you'd have to compute that:

```
def archspiral1(s):
    x = 0
    y = 0
    for c in range(100):
        yield (x, y)
        theta = float(sqrt(x^2 + y^2)/r)
        f = float(s/sqrt(1 + theta^2))
        dx = f*(1*x - theta*y)
        dy = f*(theta*x + 1*y)
        if theta == 0: dx = s
        x += dx
        y += dy
```

### Exact curve but approximate distances

Or you could consider the change in $\theta$ induced by such a step in tangent direction. If you look at the derivative, then you notice that the radial component of that distance is $r$ while the tangential (to the circle) component is $r\theta$. So you have something like

$$s = x\sqrt{1+\theta^2}\qquad r\left(\theta_2-\theta_1\right) = x \\
\theta_2=\theta_1+\frac s{r\sqrt{1+\theta_1^2}}$$

```
def archspiral2(s):
    theta = s/2
    for c in range(100):
        yield (r*theta*cos(theta), r*theta*sin(theta))
        theta += s/(r*sqrt(1 + theta^2))
```

[image: Figure of archimedean spirals]